# Extract property chain from a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Imagine I've the following code:

```
public void DoSomething<TU,TV>(Func<TU,TV> valueGetter)
{
    TV extractedValue = valueGetter(_someFields);
    //Here, how to get from  valueGetter the properties used to get the value.
    PropertyInfo[] properties = ....;//["SubObject", "SubSubObject", "Property"]

}
DoSomething((x)=>x.SubObject.SubSubObject.Property)//Let admit that this path always contains only properties, never methods
```

I'm looking too extract an array of PropertyInfo, containing each property in the path to get the object through reflection.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The very cheap way is like this:

```
  public void DoSomething<TU, TV>(Expression<Func<TU, TV>> valueGetterExpr)
  {
    var str = valueGetterExpr.ToString();
    // now 'str' holds string representation of the lambda expression
  }
```

A more structured approach is similar to this:

```
  public void DoSomething<TU, TV>(Expression<Func<TU, TV>> valueGetterExpr)
  {
    var expr = valueGetterExpr.Body;
    var li = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    while (!(expr is ParameterExpression))
    {
      if (!(expr is MemberExpression me))
        throw new Exception("Unexpected kind");

      if (!(me.Member is PropertyInfo pi))
        throw new Exception("Unexpected kind");

      li.Add(pi);
      expr = me.Expression;
    }
    // now 'li' holds all the properties
  }
```

The order is reversed compared to what you said. You may reverse the `List<>` in place with `li.Reverse();`, or you can use a `new Stack<...>()` instead of a `new List<...>()`, "push" instead of "add", and do `.ToArray()` on your stack after the loop.

In either case, call my method with e.g. `DoSomething((DateTime x) => x.TimeOfDay.TotalHours);`.

Longer example call: `DoSomething((System.Threading.Thread x) => x.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.Length);`

If you want to get the plain `Func<,>` back, you use:

```
var func = valueGetterExpr.Compile();
var extractedValue = func(_someFields);
```

I am sure this can be improved in several ways.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however you'd need to proceed on the `ExpressionTree` rather than just a func. Check official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) from our beloved Microsoft. That would require a lot of reflection, actually, so don't do if performance is a must; in such a case you have to ship more info into your method, like tuple `(function, metadata)`.

Comment: How do goes from Func to Expression? I know this is not performances good, results will be cached, but either it's this, either I've to specify manually myself an array of property for a lot of models and hopping this is  always updated in accordance of the provided value.

Comment: You just change input's type. Other code is the same, since exactly the same lambda expressions is passed as an instance of the `ExpressionTree`.

Comment: I managed to get `MemberExpression`, but from there, I cannot find how to get PropertyInfos

Comment: You read the member's name and the apply reflection on the appropriate type to get the member you're interested in defined as `PropertyInfo` or `WhateverInfo`. As I told you: there is A LOT OF reflection involved.